# Do not set $? to non-zero on Control+C

Tags: command-line, zsh, signals

My `$PS1` in Zsh includes this expression: `%(?. %?.)`
It means «if exit code of previous command (`$?`) is true, show `$?`, else show nothing».
This is generally useful, but one thing annoys me: shells set return code of last command to non-zero when I press Control+C without running a command!  Zsh sets it to 1, Bash sets it to 130.  Dash is the only shell on my system that does not reset it on Control+C.

How to reproduce:

1. Launch zsh or bash.
2. Press Control+C.
3. `echo $?`.

Is there a way to turn off this behavior on Zsh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to turn it off.

First thought is to have preexec set a variable that indicates a command was run.  If you pressed Ctrl+C at the prompt, it wouldn't get set.

```
precmd() {
    exit_status=$?
    if ! $ran_something; then
        exit_status=0
    fi
    ran_something=false
}
preexec() {
    ran_something=true
}
show_non_zero_exit_status() {
    case $exit_status in
    0)
        :;;
    *)
        echo $exit_status;;
    esac
}
PS1='$(show_non_zero_exit_status)$ '
```

But there's another similar problem: if you suspend a command, you'll get exit status 20 (zsh < 5.0.7) or 148 (bash and zsh >= 5.0.7).

To get around that, you can add `20|148` to the `case` statement above, i.e.

```
show_non_zero_exit_status() {
    case $exit_status in
    0|20|148)
        :;;
    *)
        echo $exit_status;;
    esac
}
```

If you're using zsh, make sure you have `setopt promptsubst` in your `.zshrc`.

If you're using bash, add:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=precmd
trap preexec DEBUG
```

but really you should use the more complicated DEBUG trap mentioned in https://superuser.com/a/175802/15334

Another possibility is that `setopt printexitvalue` is close enough to what you want.

Comment: Thank you!  `setopt printexitvalue` seems to do what I want (make non-zero exit code immediately visible), and does not require prompt_subst, which I try my best to keep off).  It would be better if its output wasn't identical to one after a background job has quit though, but it's not a big deal.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this question still interests people in 2019...

`130` is a pretty rare exit status (I believe UNIX as implemented in the early days recognizes exit statuses only up to 128) - so just ignore it.

```
# pseudocode

if exit_status == 0 then
    do nothing
else
    if exit_status == 130 then
        do nothing
    else
        print " [red]exit_status[/red]"
```

In `zsh` terms, it translates to:

```
%(0?..%(130?.. %F{red}%?%f))
```

**Update:** you wrote that `zsh` sets the exit code to `1` on `Ctrl-C` and `bash` to `130`. Here, in 2019, both `bash` and `zsh` return `130`.